# How to limit depth of recursion in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a recursion here:

```
located_on(A,B,[move(A,B)|_]).
located_on(B,L,[_|S]) :- located_on(B,L,S).
```

When I ask `located_on(a,b,X).` I get as follows, which is infinite.

```
X = [] ;
X = [move(a, b)|_G4037] ;
X = [_G4036] ;
X = [_G4036, move(a, b)|_G4040] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039, move(a, b)|_G4043] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039, _G4042] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039, _G4042, move(a, b)|_G4046] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039, _G4042, _G4045] ;
X = [_G4036, _G4039, _G4042, _G4045, move(a, b)|_G4049]
```

How can I limit the depth of recursion and get finite number of results?

I tried to use:

```
located_on(A,B,[move(A,B)|_]).
located_on(B,L,[_|S]) :- located_on(B,L,S),length(S,N),N<5.
```

But I got **out of local stack**.

Comment: Your solutions are clearly wrong. Why don't you state the problem more clearly in your previous question ? This one is useless

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
length(X,N),
located_on(a,b,X).
```

is called [*iterative deepening*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search).

Gotta *luv* Prolog!

Comment: @false the only difference I could see is that with `between` N starts from 1, instead of from 0. Is that what's wrong? thanks.

Comment: There is a deeper reason why an unrealistically hight upper bound is misleading: such an upper bound makes the program terminate and thus hides the price we have to pay very often for iterative deepening: The loss of a complete search procedure. While we find all answers,we can never be for sure that there is not another one lurking around.

Comment: @false IOW it's a *hack*. ... but without the upper bound it is now at least *evident* that the search is unbound, right? So ID is not the Right Thing to do. As WP puts it, it's an *uninformed* search.

Comment: This is a general problem: There are things you can decide (= a terminating algorithm exists), and then are things where no algorithm exists but which are still interesting: They might only be semi-decidable. For those, iterative deepening is not that bad. And it is incredibly fast to write and very space efficient.

Comment: *Space* efficient :) because it *re-does* a lot of stuff.

Comment: There are ways to extend ID - as with noting whether or not we have reached the current limit. And if we have not, we may abort the search. But that is an improvement.

Comment: Re Space efficiency: Yes it re-does some stuff, but it depends on the branching factor. If it is big enough the overheads are neglectable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41369/discussion-between-false-and-will-ness)